# How to deserialize SAML request in php - Can't install LightSAML

Tags: php, laravel, saml

I am trying to install LightSAML https://packagist.org/packages/lightsaml/lightsaml, into a Laravel app, to do some very basic deserialization of a HTTP POST request, but getting errors:

```
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

 Problem 1
 - Conclusion: don't install lightsaml/lightsaml 1.3.6
 .....

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

It does seem a little old so not sure if I can make it work at all - if not, can anyone suggest even simpler means of deserializing and accessing the individual attributes of a SAML request?

I have also seen https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml, however it looks like it does more than I need - I don't need to do the actual auth part using SAML, I merely need to accept a SAML http post and use that data for my own bespoke auth token creation.

Comment: did u find solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I had to add this to composer and update:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/frostieDE/lightSAML"
    }
],
```

Answer (score 1):

If the idea is just to decode the `SAMLResponse` data that's being `POST`'ed to your endpoint, then you can achieve that easily (as long as it's not encrypted).

The `SAMLResponse` is base64 encoded, so you just have to decode it. In the controller method where you're receiving the data, you'll do something like:

```
// Decode the data into the original XML document
$xmlPayload = base64_decode($request->get('SAMLResponse'));
```

Now, the XML data you've just decoded, needs to be parsed. Given the document is small, using `DOMDocument` should be enough:

```
// Load the XML document
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xmlPayload);

// Traverse User elements
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('Attribute') as $attribute) {
    var_dump($attribute->nodeName.'[@'.$attribute->getAttribute('Name').'] -> '.$attribute->nodeValue);
}
```

That will output something like:

```
string(34) "saml2:Attribute[@firstName] -> Ray"
string(37) "saml2:Attribute[@lastName] -> Charles"
string(48) "saml2:Attribute[@email] -> ray.charles@music.com"
string(48) "saml2:Attribute[@login] -> ray.charles@music.com"
string(44) "saml2:Attribute[@id] -> 11uboeg2g0bKNxyk01z7"
```

This is just an example, since the attributes will probably change (depending on how your Single Sign On IdP is set).

I tested with a payload from Okta.

Comment: with ```$xmlPayload = base64_decode($request->get('SAMLResponse'));``` cant decode it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the solution is in error:  Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. I guess that in your libs must be a conflict with LightSaml. Just incompatible.

Perhaps there's a composer.lock file in /Users/user/.composer or other place that hinders the update.

Try that steps:

1. got inside global composer folder (C:\Users\your_name\AppData\Roaming\Composer)
2. edited the composer.json (added to require : "your_package" : "number.*" )
3. in command line: composer global update.

As you wrote, solution might be adding:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/frostieDE/lightSAML"
    }
],
```

Good luck